# Last days I was trying to add api pagination for my recycler view. But I faced a problem such

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

```
override fun setAdapter() {
    adapter = WaybillAdapter(items, activity!!, this, recyclerView)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

I am updating my adapter when I should add items for my recycler like

```
override fun addWaybills(list: ArrayList<Data>) {
     items.addAll(list)
     adapter.setLoaded(true)
}
```

Add my position of an recycler is jumping to start.
My question is how should update adapter by not changing current position?

Comment: post recyclerview adapter and activity code if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activitie's `onCreate` or fragment's `onCreateView` create initialize your adapter with empty `ArrayList` and later when you fetch your data add items to your arraylist and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: When I call function `setAdapter` in `onCreateView` studio tells me `recyclerView is null`, so I guess I can't call it. When I use `onViewCreated` `notifyDataSetChanged` not working. Could you help me?